# Leaflet markers refresh with ajax filter success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet

I am not sure, how to reload the map or rather reload all available markers, after this ajax filter is on success. I am not really good with Jquery and JS, so please bear with me.

Here is what I have in the page:

```
<div id="mapwrap"></div> //this is my Leaflet map div
<div id="response"></div> //this is where the results are inserted
<div id="postlist"><?php post_liste();?></div>
```

The filtering of the posts works fine, the marker divs are added for each item, however I cannot get the map to resize/reload/refresh or remove/refresh/reload the marker array.

This is the ajax filter, which is called right after my divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
            $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            $('#postlist').remove();
            // reload markers, I tried:
            // map.clearLayers();
            // map._resetView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom(), true);
            // map.invalidateSize();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The Map script itself is in another file.

```
// for rendering the Leaflet Map

var map;

(function ($) { 
  $(document).ready(function () {
map = L.map('mapwrap', {scrollWheelZoom: false}).setView([51.51, 9.19], 6);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery &copy; <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  //layers: [ group ],
}).addTo( map ); 

var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize:     [43, 57],
    iconAnchor:   [21, 57],
    popupAnchor:  [0, -43],
  }
});

var markers = [];

var marker = [];
$.each($('.marker'), function () {
  var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
  var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
  var name = $(this).attr('data-title');
  var link = $(this).attr('data-url');
  var icon = $(this).attr('data-icon');
  marker = [ name, lat, lng, icon, link ];
  markers.push(marker);
});

var group = new L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

  var myIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: markers[i][3] });
  var marker = new L.marker([markers[i][1],markers[i][2]], {icon: myIcon });
      marker.bindPopup(markers[i][0])
      marker.addTo(group);
}

// this is for getting different zoom levels on sub-pages, where the mapwrap is smaller
$(window).on('orientationchange pageshow resize', function () {
    $("#mapwrap").height();
    map.invalidateSize();
    if ($("#mapwrap").height() < 400 ) { map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), { maxZoom: 10 }); }
}).trigger('resize');

  });
})(jQuery);
```

I thought maybe I could set a kind of Timeout to the map script function, but that didn't work. The thing is, whatever I put into the function beginning with map.something, doesn't work - console doesn't give me any clues.

What would be possible? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Showing how and where you insert your map script file, as well as your map code, would highly help people understanding your situation.

Comment: the div "mapwrap" is where the map gets inserted, adding the map script in a sec

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you wrap your code into so many IIFE's.

You are trying to re-use a variable `map` between different `<script>`'s, but it is defined in a function scope / closure. Therefore it is not accessible from outside that scope. Instead, you should declare it globally (either `map`, `window.map` or `var map` at the root scope, i.e. not inside any `function`)

```js
// AJAX code unchanged, using map variable.

// In your map script
var map;

$(document).ready(function () {
  // do your stuff but DO NOT re-declare `var map`, just re-use `map`.
  map = L.map('mapwrap', options);
});
```

Make sure you understand [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: thank you, that helped a bit, at least the variable get's accepted in the ajax function, now I have to find the correct solution for refreshing the markers...